# How to search in a dictionary values and keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
graph = [["Portugal","Spain"],["Spain","France"],["France","Belgium","Germany"],
         ["Canada","United States"]]
```

So i got this graph, and i want to search in it. Imagine that i am in portugal and i want to know how many countries i can visit, so from portugal i can go to spain, and then to france and then i can choose between germany, belgium. So the function that i want to do should return 5, that are all the countries i can visit.

```
def convert(graph):
    dic = {}
    for lista in graph:
        dic[lista[0]] = set()
        for i in range(1,len(lista)):
            dic[lista[0]].add(lista[i])
    return dic
```

i convert that graph to a dictionary and i got this

```
{'Canada': ['United States'], 'Spain':['France'], 'Portugal':['Spain'],
 'France':['Belgium', 'Germany']}
```

but i don't what to do know.

Comment: Imagine that inside the graph there was another element for Belgium so that from Belgium you can also visit the Netherlands. In this case what would the result be for Portugal? Would the result then be 6 because from Belgium you can visit the Netherlands or would it still be 5 because if you visit the Netherlands you cannot also visit Germany?

Comment: well, nice one ahah, i guess if you visit netherland then you can go back to belgium and visit germany, but i am not sure

Answer (score 0):

You could go for:

```
from itertools import dropwhile 

graph = [["Portugal","Spain"],["Spain","France"],["France","Belgium","Germany"],["Canada","United States"]]

def get_destinations(start, lst):
    # dropwhile discards any item that does not fulfill the predicate
    # in this example it discards everything that has not start at the first position
    rest = list(dropwhile(lambda x: x[0] != start, graph))

    # here, we combine (zip) the rest with the next offset
    # and compare the last item (len(item) - 1) with 
    # the first item of the next sublist
    destinations = [y
                    for x, y in zip(rest, rest[1:])
                    if x[len(x) - 1] == y[0]]

    # filter out duplicates and return the result
    return {item for lst in destinations for item in lst}

destinations = get_destinations("Portugal", graph)
print(destinations)
```

Which yields

```
{'France', 'Spain', 'Belgium', 'Germany'}
```

First, we drop every item which does not equal to `start`, then we collect every item where the last subitem equals the following first subitem. In the end we form a set of the subgraph.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help, i will use your code and i will try to understand it

Comment: it's quite difficult to understand that function because i am a beginner in pyhton

Comment: @TBOTL: Added some explanations.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but `x[0] is not start` is brittle as hell; that's an identity based test, so it only works if both strings are interned (which happens implicitly for many string literals, but wouldn't apply to random strings acquired by I/O, or construction from other strings). You want `x[0] != start`, which is a value comparison, not identity comparison. More minor, no reason to pass generator expression to `set` constructor, just use a set comprehension: `{item for lst in destinations for item in lst}` or just flatten with `chain`: `set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(destinations))`